# Redux state : Add or replace

Tags: javascript, redux, state

Let's say I'm building an online streaming website

route /artist/name: (displaying a list of the artist's albums)
current state :

```js
{ 
  artist: 'Eminem', 
  albums: [{name: 'MMLP', songs: [listofsongids]}, {name: 'Relapse', songs: [...]}]
}
```

route /artist/name/albums/albumid: (displaying a list of the albums' songs)
current state :

```js
{ 
  artist: 'Eminem', 
  albums: [{name: 'MMLP', songs: [listofsongids]}, {name: 'Relapse', songs: [...]}], 
  songs: {song1: {lyrics: '...', ...}, song2: {...}}
}
```

If I immediately switch route to visit another album should I replace the
songs property of the state with a new list or just add to it and retrieve
the relevant ones by the current album song list ids?

On github Dan Abramov suggests to never empty the state on route changes:
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1235

I'm curious as to how you guys would handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be a hard question to accept an answer for as you will find people will have their preference either way, and in the end, there is no single *correct* answer.  It will depend on your app, the data it uses and the requirements you are going for, but I will give you my opinion anyway.

Given you have the ids and you can look up `songs` easily using the `id` as the object key and the low chance (I assume) that the song data is going to change between loads, I would wouldn't worry to empty it and just add new songs to as they're required.

This will make switching back to a previously loaded album much faster which will be nicer for the user.

If you're particularly worried about performance of looking up the songs as the collection grows, you can use [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) to remove unnecessary lookups.

In fact, the more [normalized you can get the data](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html), the less removing data from the state I would do.  You could keep every `album` the user has loaded, regardless of `artist`, and even keep every `artist` too and just change values in the store for `selectedArtist` and `selectedAlbum`.

This would also give you more options on when you load the data.  For example, you could load all the albums for an artist in the background if the user hovers their mouse over the artist for 3 seconds, or start loading songs in the background as soon as the `/artist/name` route is hit.

Comment: Thank you, your answer has helped me. So to resume this having a state like this:
{
  artists: {collection of artists},
  albums: {collection of albums from different artists},
  songs: {collection of songs from different artists and albums}
}
Would be your goto solution?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing exactly what you're building and your requirements, but yeah. Normalise as much as possible to give yourself more freedom.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I've looked around a bit more and stumbled on redux-orm. It got me really interested. The only downside to it for me is the need to predefine every fields on a model!

Comment: Another library I've seen (but not used myself) is [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr).